# AlamofireCoreData Pod

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alamofire

I'm trying to use AlamofireCoreData Pod but got an issue. Every value are nil; (see console log message below)

Here my Core Data, News Class

```
extension News {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<News> {
        return NSFetchRequest<News>(entityName: "News")
    }

    @NSManaged public var content: String?
    @NSManaged public var created_at: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var date_pub_beg: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var date_pub_end: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var id: Int16
    @NSManaged public var results: Bool
    @NSManaged public var rotation: Bool
    @NSManaged public var summary: String?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var updated_at: NSDate?

}
```

In my swift file I do

```
private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

func getNews(url: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)  {

        Alamofire.request(url).responseInsert(context: context, type: Many<News>.self) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case let .success(news):
                print (news)
                completion(true)
            case .failure:
                // handle error
                completion(false)

                print("Erreur")
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling my func print this in console log, call to the api seems to work but no data seems to be parse.

```
[<News: 0x60800009fef0> (entity: News; id: 0x60800003c880 <x-coredata:///News/tBB28D896-033A-4084-807A-6A31993B8F2F2> ; data: {
    content = nil;
    "created_at" = nil;
    "date_pub_beg" = nil;
    "date_pub_end" = nil;
    id = 0;
    results = nil;
    rotation = nil;
    summary = nil;
    title = nil;
    "updated_at" = nil;
}), <News: 0x608000282170> (entity: News; id: 0x60800003ba00 <x-coredata:///News/tBB28D896-033A-4084-807A-6A31993B8F2F3> ; data: {
    content = nil;
    "created_at" = nil;
    "date_pub_beg" = nil;
    "date_pub_end" = nil;
    id = 0;
    results = nil;
    rotation = nil;
    summary = nil;
    title = nil;
    "updated_at" = nil;
})]
```

Here what my API sent, JSON REST API made with Rails.

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Victoire de la France",
        date_pub_beg: "2017-11-27",
        date_pub_end: "2017-12-31",
        summary: "La France remporte la Coupe Davis.",
        content: "<div>Au terme du dernier match, la France remporte la <strong>Coupe Davis.</strong></div>",
        created_at: "2017-11-27T14:18:07.527Z",
        updated_at: "2017-11-27T14:18:07.527Z",
        results: false,
        rotation: false
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Test d'article",
        date_pub_beg: "2017-09-05",
        date_pub_end: "2017-09-06",
        summary: "Ceci est un test, AH BON ?",
        content: "<div><strong>Petit test pour voir !</strong></div><ul><li>test 1</li><li>test 2</li><li>test 3</li></ul><div><br></div>",
        created_at: "2017-09-05T07:43:18.011Z",
        updated_at: "2017-11-27T14:42:18.907Z",
        results: false,
        rotation: false
    }
]
```

Everything seems to be ok, don't understand why those nil values.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I use Alamofire a little bit different and it works fine. I've never seen this implementation as you did. Try this

```
func getNews(url: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)  {        
    var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.SessionManager?
    alamoFireManager?.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:nil)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response.result.value!)
                completion(true)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
    }
}
```

and if you have some authentication header, you can place it in headers parameter as an array `["Authorization":yourkey]`

To complement, I use alamoFireManager as a singleton (global).

and I have this extension to help debugging:

```
extension Request {
    public func debugLog() -> Self {
        #if DEBUG
            debugPrint(self)
        #endif
        return self
    }
}
```

Use:

```
func getNews(url: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)  {        
    var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.SessionManager?
    alamoFireManager?.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:nil)
        .debugLog() // <<<-----
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response.result.value!)
                completion(true)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
    }
}
```

and it will print your request

Bonne chance

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you save and you read CoreData datas on different thread. If you called your method getNews() on the main thread Alamofire in the callbacks methods is in a background thread. You have to retrieved your datas from the private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext with the context where you saved. I have this kind of problem when I was using CoreData. Now I used to implement CoreData with MagicalRecord.